# Detect CJK characters in PHP

Tags: utf-8, cjk, language-detection

I've got an input box that allows UTF8 characters -- can I detect whether the characters are in Chinese, Japanese, or Korean programmatically (part of some Unicode range, perhaps)? I would change search methods depending on if MySQL's fulltext searching would work (it won't work for CJK characters).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CJK characters are restricted to certain [Unicode Blocks](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/index.htm). You need to check the characters if they are inside these blocks, and should consider surrogates (32bit characters) too.

Answer (score 13):

```
// is chinese, japanese or korean language
function isCjk($string) {
    return isChinese($string) || isJapanese($string) || isKorean($string);
}

function isChinese($string) {
    return preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $string);
}

function isJapanese($string) {
    return preg_match('/[\x{4E00}-\x{9FBF}\x{3040}-\x{309F}\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}]/u', $string);
}

function isKorean($string) {
    return preg_match('/[\x{3130}-\x{318F}\x{AC00}-\x{D7AF}]/u', $string);
}
```

Comment: OMG, thank you!! This should be the accepted answer - and it's such a simple one!

Comment: simplicity is the ultimate sophistication :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to detect whether a character is a (Chinese or Japanese or Korean) character? Or do you want to tell Chinese characters apart from Japanese characters? The former is easy; the latter is in many cases impossible, due to Han Unification.